# Google Analytics Custom Dimensions Not Feeding Through

Tags: google-analytics

I have setup custom dimensions as follows

[image]

My source code shows as this:

```
<script>
    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Manager');
    ga('set', 'dimension2', 'Recruitment');
    ga('set', 'dimension3', 'Leave');

</script>
```

It's been in place for 24 hours. However when I go to my Google Analytics account > Home > Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages, and then add any of the custom dimensions I've created, no data is brought back.

Am I doing something terribly wrong or does everything look ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap it so that it is this way:

```
<script>
    window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');

    ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Manager');
    ga('set', 'dimension2', 'Recruitment');
    ga('set', 'dimension3', 'Leave');

    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

This is because the "hit" doesn't get sent with ga set. The ga send is the only hit there.